Creating polynomials with even and odd values at specific sets
If we wish to shortly write the expression
$$
\begin{cases}
    1  & ~~  n \equiv 0 \bmod{2}~~ \\
    -1 &  ~~ n \equiv 1 \bmod{2} 
\end{cases}
$$
the obvious way to do so is by taking $(-1)^n$.
It is less obvious, but still somewhat common, to write $(-1)^{\frac{n^2-1}{8}}$ for
$$
\begin{cases}
    1  & ~~  n \equiv 1,7 \bmod{8}~~ \\
    -1 &  ~~ n \equiv 3,5 \bmod{8} 
\end{cases}
$$
where $n=2k+1$ is assumed to be odd. This works since $n^2 -1 = (n+1)(n-1)=4k(k+1)$. This is always divisible by $8$, and $\frac{n^2-1}{8}=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ is even iff one of $k, k+1$ is divisible by $4$. This happens exactly when $k=4l$ of $k+1=4r$ for some $l,r\in \Bbb{Z}$, which yields $n=8l+1$ or $n=2(4r-1)+1=8r-1$.
Questions. Fix $d\in \Bbb{N}$.

Given a set $A$ which is the union of some cosets of the subgroup $d \Bbb{Z}$ of $\Bbb{Z}$, is there a polynomial $P\in \Bbb{Q} [X]$ s.t. $P(n)$ is even iff $n\in A$, and odd otherwise, for every integer $n$?
If such a polynomial exists, is there an algorithm to construct it explicitly?
Can we construct it s.t. $P \in \frac{1}{d} \Bbb Z [X]$, like in the second example?


If $P(x)$ is a rational polynomial which always evaluates as an integer when $x$ is an integer,  then  there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $P(m+n)\equiv P(m)\pmod2$ for all integers $m.$ This means your set must be periodic.

Thanks. And will it be possible for every $n$-periodic set? With a polynomial $P$ such that $n\cdot P \in \Bbb{Z}[X]$? Can you think of a sketch of an algorithm to practically compute it?

No idea. I told you what I know.
